# Tensorflow Extended - nested structures assert failure during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tfx

I am attempting to create my own TFX pipeline based on Tensorflow's TFX [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/components_keras) with my own tabular dataset. So I simply replace their dataset with my own and keep large portions of the existing code.

However, when I reach the training component - Trainer - the assertion error `assert_same_structure` fails because of dissimilar nested structures:

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.
First structure: type=SparseTensorSpec str=SparseTensorSpec(TensorShape([40, None]), tf.int64)
Second structure: type=Tensor str=Tensor("Address:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)
More specifically: Substructure "type=SparseTensorSpec str=SparseTensorSpec(TensorShape([40, None]), tf.int64)" is a sequence, while substructure "type=Tensor str=Tensor("Address:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64)" is not
Entire first structure:
.
Entire second structure:
.
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? It is quite hard to figure out what is happening backstage in the TFX pipeline.

Comment: What type of dataset are you using. Can you please share your dataset for us to reproduce this issue. Thanks!